# Programmatically Importing Nodes from one page to another another

Tags: views

I want to import node that are on one page to another programmatically.

Have tried to do by two method

```
$my_view_name = 'view name';
$my_display_name = 'display name';

$my_view = views_get_view($my_view_name);
if ( is_object($my_view) ) { 
  $my_view->set_display($my_display_name);
  $my_view->$nid;
return $my_view

views_embed_view('Machine name', 'Page name', $nid);
```

Trying to get all the nodes from one page and use them in another page to do some operations. So in the first page I have written some sql queries to get a node. Now in the second page I want all those nodes without writing the sql queries. So whenever someone updates the first page, the person does not have to go to second page and update the sql queries over there

Comment: Unfortunately unclear what exactly you are trying to achieve. A view is no content, it's just a layer to display content. Content is in the database.

Comment: Trying to get all the nodes from one page and use them in another page to do some operations. So in the first page I have written some sql queries to get a node. Now in the second page I want all those nodes without writing the sql queries. So whenever someone updates the first page, the person does not have to go to second page and update the sql queries over there.

Comment: And what's that view?

Comment: The first page view.

Comment: In your question's title by page you mean a "Basic page" node, not a different site like example-foo.com and example-bar.com, right? And with importing you mean "displaying", right? That's one and the same page/site you are talking about, right? Just guessing. As it's still absolutely unclear to me.

Comment: So lets us consider a two pages Page_foo and page_bar. Now page_foo has thousands of nids which has loaded using some sql query.
I have to get the nids from page_foo to page_bar(which is a custom module i wrote) and do some other operation on these nids on page_bar.
The reason I trying to do this is because nids from page_foo is been manipulated many times. So if the nids gets manipulated in page_foo it should automatically get affected to page_bar too